# ffmpeg only shows one Image?

Tags: image, ffmpeg, slideshow

Here are the images I have in my folder:

```
img001.png
img002.png
```

They are stored in `c:/frames`.

Because that my frames are not shown correctly, used the FPS filter video shown below (documentation from https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Slideshow):

```
ffmpeg -r 1/5 -i img%03d.png -c:v libx264 -vf fps=25 -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4
```

I tried running on my VLC media player but it still doesn't work. It only shows one image.

Answer (score 0):

The last frame of an image sequence will only be shown for an instant. Use tpad filter to clone it once and then apply other filters like fps.

`ffmpeg -framerate 1/5 -i img%03d.png -vf "tpad=stop=1:stop_mode=clone,fps=25" -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:v libx264 out.mp4`

Comment: It still doenst work, it only shows one frame